# handle the submit button

Tags: forms

Hello guys i am trying to add data to one of my tables... when the submit button is pressed.
I have the following script:

```
function review_m_admin_settings_form($node){
    $form = array();

    $form['overview'] = array(
        '#markup' => t('This interface allow adminss to manage general content types and vote them up!'),
    );
    $form['select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Choose a content type!',
        '#options' => node_get_types('names'),
    );
    $form['mark'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Give a mark to the content type(1 to 10)!',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 2,
    );
    $form['text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => 'leave a feedback!',
        '#cols' => 60,
        '#resizable' => FALSE,
        '#rows' => 5,
    );
    $form['created'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Enter the date!',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send review'),
        '#weight' => 10,
    );
    $form['action'] = $url;
    return $form;
}
```

this is my form.... i called the function with the _submit at the end .. **but it doesn't work!**

```
    function review_m_admin_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    if(!isset($node->text)){
        $node->text = '';
        }
        if(!isset($node->created)){
            $node->created = '';
        }
        db_query(
            'INSERT INTO {review_m} (rid, nid, uid, mark, text, created)'
            . "VALUES (%d, %d, %d, '%s', '%s')",
            $node->rid,
            $node->nid,
            $node->uid,
            $node->mark,
            $node->text,
            $node->created
        );
}
```

**Help!**

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?  Do you get any error messages? Have you checked the watchdog at `admin/reports/dblog`?

Comment: You have set [form action](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#action) to `$form['action'] = $url` but I dont see `$url` being declared anywhere in code that you have posted, can you post the complete code ? Or have you forgot to declare `$url` ?

Comment: `$node` doesn't appear to be declared in `_submit` either.

Comment: well i get to errors:

Comment: warning: Creating default object from empty value in D:\work\test\drupal\sites\all\modules\review_m\review_m.module on line 64.

Comment: @emcee22 Can you point out Line 64 in your code ?

Comment: this is line 64: **$node->text = '';** from my _submit function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to an object property without declaring the object.  Try this:

```
function review_m_admin_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $node = new stdClass();
```

There's actually not any need to check if $node->text isset either because we know we haven't set it already.

You also need to pull your form values from the `$form_state` variable.  For example:

```
$node->text = $form_state['values']['text']
```